# Estimating number of consecutive pairs in a list

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list of `0/1` values i.e.

```
MyList = [0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0]
```

My goal is 2 calculate number of pairs like `(0,0) and (0,1)`.

In above example, there are 5 pairs of `(0,0)` (i.e. first, 2nd, 3rd, and eighth, ninth positions), and for `(0,1)` there are 3 such occurrences.

Is there any function/method available to achieve this?

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question and put there expected output?

Comment: @AndrejKesely I have added expected result for the given example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `collections.Counter`:

```py
from collections import Counter

lst = [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0]

c = Counter(zip(lst, lst[1:]))

print(f"{c[(0, 0)]=}")
print(f"{c[(0, 1)]=}")
```

Prints:

```
c[(0, 0)]=5
c[(0, 1)]=3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an iterator of subsequent pairs from your list with `zip` and them check if the pairs are equal to the target pair:

```
def calculate_pairs(lst, pair=(0, 0)):
    return sum((i, j) == pair for i, j in zip(MyList[:-1], MyList[1:]))

MyList = [0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0]

calculate_pairs(MyList, pair=(0, 0))
>> 5
calculate_pairs(MyList, pair=(0, 1))
>> 3
```